# How does the Master of Shadow prestige class affect the Shadowcaster class?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, forgotten-realms, prestige-class

I am playing a Forgotten Realms (3.5e) campaign as a *Shadowcaster* and I was looking into taking the prestige class *Master of Shadow*.  Would this prestige class effect whether or not I can get Apprentice and Master mysteries, and would it affect the way they are cast (treated as a spell, spell-like ability, or supernatural ability)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is defined on *Tome of Magic* pg. 117:

> #### PRESTIGE CLASS CASTING ADVANCEMENTS
>
> When a shadowcaster gains new casting class levels from
>   advancement within a prestige class, this includes the
>   knowledge of new fundamentals, and the transformation
>   of lower-level path mysteries into spell-like or supernatural
>   abilities. It does not include gaining bonus feats for learning
>   new paths or any other shadowcaster class features.

So yes, you get initiate and master paths as normal for a shadowcaster of a level equal to your shadowcaster level plus master of shadow level minus 1. Unfortunately, the question of whether or not your fundamentals grow in usage frequency is unclear: it specifies “knowledge of **new** fundamentals,” but not improvements in using fundamentals in general. It is probably intended to be included, since it’s from the same shadowcaster class feature, and because it would be inane to not include it, but you’ll have to double-check that with your DM.

Comment: Would this also apply to the usage of fundamentals changing as well or is that considered a class feature?

Comment: @irishtatertot25 “this includes the knowledge of new fundamentals”

Comment: I got that part, I was referring to when the usage of fundamentals goes from 3/day to infinite.

Comment: @irishtatertot25 Hm, fair, that’s unclear. Unfortunately, you’re going to have to ask your DM; it’s unclear. I would certainly include them, but you’ll have to check with the person running your game. Basically, *Tome of Magic* isn’t a particularly well-written or well-edited book, and I say that as someone whose favorite class is the binder. At least you aren’t trying the truenamer; that class doesn’t even work.